# events not emitting on tap in components

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

See the code here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AIQOcR&v=165, I would like to make the FabItem component emit a tap so I can build the menu but events are not emitting

Was able to fix it with the following code,

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AIQOcR&v=169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did a simple copy/paste mistake, you are emitting `onButtonTap` from FabItem but listening to `onFabItemTap` in the Main component.

Comment: Yes you are correct, fixed it but it's not this, still no emit when the 3 buttons are animated, see https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AIQOcR&v=167

Comment: seems like the animation somehow disables taps

Comment: You are correct and after looking at your layouts, that's expected. You are placing the buttons in AbsoluteLayout within the space given for the plus button, since the background is transparent it's visible even when it gets out of bounds but it won't be clickable.

Comment: look at this version https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AIQOcR&v=168 I made a button which does'nt animate at the top and it's clickable